# How to programmatically create a GraphQl request

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

Currently I am trying to make a graphql POST request in Spring Boot. This is my request :

`mutation { update(bank: {id : "c0ad2522-c40c-4478-8b6f-b0261eab1116", bank : "bankExample", IBAN : "1234", currency : "GBP" }){ id } }`

How can I programatically create the above mentioned query in Java. Since the syntax is not a json is there a builder or an object mapper for this? I’ve tried to check everywhere but could not find an example or documentation. I'm trying to make this call between two spring boot microservices with two different graphql schemas.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Hi Andrei, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you read: https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/ before? That should be a good start for what you are looking for :)

Comment: Hi @KingDarBoja , in that example a schema is generated and therefore queries can be executed based on that schema. I am interested in creating a GraphQL query spring boot as a client and not as a server. The microservice from which Im trying to make a call already has its own GraphQL schema

Comment: Did you investigate these [GraphQL clients for Java](https://graphql.org/code/#java-android)?

Comment: @ChinHuang yes, but the client library for Java is not maintained

Comment: I recommend the Apollo Android client. It was designed for Android but can be used outside of the android ecosystem. I use it with the spring stack. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started-java/